# kendoTabStrip - Initially loads as bullet list

Tags: kendo-ui

I don't know if I am the only one noticing this, but I have a application that uses a kendoTabStrip and when the page initially loads before the tabstrip is initialized, the page shows a bulleted list. Does anyone know how to prevent it?

Here is what my HTML looks like.

```
<div id="tabstrip" style="width:1230px">
        <ul>
            <li class="k-state-active">
                Tab1
            </li>
            <li>
                Tab2
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <div id="Grid1"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="Grid2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should not see such flickering effect. It sounds like your page is pretty heavy. You can try to set the whole tabstrip with style *display:none* and after initializing it to show() it with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had to do. The issue was more noticeable in IE, you couldn't notice it in Firefox and Chrome.